# Как вывести bitmap на экран?

Tags: delphi

Есть bmp:tbitmap  с картинкой внутри. Как эту картинку вывести на нулевой DC (на экран)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто! Битмап обладает таким свойством, как идентификатор контекста устройства вывода. Вод, собственно, код:

```
procedure print_to_screen(fname:string);
var bmp:Tcanvas;   // это канва для рисования на рабочем столе
pic:Tbitmap;       // здесь будет находиться рисунок
begin
pic:=TbitMap.create();
pic.LoadFromFile(fname);  // загружаем рисунок
bmp:=Tcanvas.create();
bmp.Handle:=getDC(0);    // присваиваем идентификатор контекста устройства вывода
bmp.Draw(0,0,pic);       // рисуем
bmp.Brush.Color:=clwhite;  // еще рисуем...
bmp.Rectangle(0,0,1000,100);
end;
```